# i have a problem in making this Diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

How can I draw a picture like this in latex??

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,outer sep=0pt,thick},place/.style={circle,,thick,
inner sep=0pt,minimum size=6mm}]
\tikzstyle{spring}=[thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.3cm,post length=0.3cm,segment length=6}]
\tikzstyle{damper}=[thick,decoration={markings,  
  mark connection node=dmp,
  mark=at position 0.5 with 
  {
    \node (dmp) [thick,inner sep=0pt,transform shape,rotate=-90,minimum width=15pt,minimum height=3pt,draw=none] {};
    \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north east)+(2.5pt,0)$) -- (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south west) -- ($(dmp.north west)+(2pt,0)$);
    \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north)+(0,-5pt)$) -- ($(dmp.north)+(0,5pt)$);
  }
}, decorate]
\tikzstyle{ground}=[fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=0.75cm,minimum height=0.3cm]



\begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]
\node (ground) [ground,anchor=north,minimum width=2cm] {};
\draw (ground.north east) -- (ground.north west);
\node (M) [yshift=-3cm,minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm] {$m$};
\draw [spring] (ground.south) -- (M.north);
\node (Pendul) at ( 1,-6) [place] {m};
\draw [thick] (M.south) -- (Pendul.north west);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and I got this:

[image]

It doesn't look so good.How can I edit and add more details to it??

Comment: didn't you ask this previously? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332906/dynamical-system-drawing

Comment: yes but added some more details now!

Comment: You could delete the old question, or edit it to add the new details and delete the new one.  BTW, impressive work with the spring, although you could have saved some effort using the spring from Circuitikz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `tikzpicture` options made it impossible to add text, so I restricted it to a scope.  (Your original scope did nothing.)  BTW, is that a 1 or an l?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope} [every node/.style={draw,outer sep=0pt,thick},place/.style={circle,,thick,
inner sep=0pt,minimum size=6mm}]
\tikzstyle{spring}=[thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.3cm,post length=0.3cm,segment length=6}]
\tikzstyle{damper}=[thick,decoration={markings,  
  mark connection node=dmp,
  mark=at position 0.5 with 
  {
    \node (dmp) [thick,inner sep=0pt,transform shape,rotate=-90,minimum width=15pt,minimum height=3pt,draw=none] {};
    \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north east)+(2.5pt,0)$) -- (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south west) -- ($(dmp.north west)+(2pt,0)$);
    \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north)+(0,-5pt)$) -- ($(dmp.north)+(0,5pt)$);
  }
}, decorate]
\tikzstyle{ground}=[fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=0.75cm,minimum height=0.3cm]

\node (ground) [ground,anchor=north,minimum width=2cm] {};
\draw (ground.north east) -- (ground.north west);
\node (M) [yshift=-3cm,minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm] {$m$};
\draw [spring] (ground.south) -- (M.north);
\node (Pendul) at ( 1,-6) [place] {m};
\draw [thick] (M.south) -- (Pendul);
\end{scope}
\path (ground.south) -- (M.north) node[midway,right=1mm] {$k$};
\draw (M.east) ++(5mm,0) -- +(5mm,0) coordinate[midway] (temp);
\draw[-latex] (temp) -- +(0,-5mm) node[midway,right] {$x$};
\draw ($(M.south)!.5!(Pendul)$) node[above right] {$l$};
\draw ($(M.south)!.5!(Pendul)$) -- +(1cm,0) node[below, xshift=5mm] {Massless Rod};
\draw[dashed] (M.south) -- +(0,-1cm) node[below] {$\theta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: thank you so much. it's l indicative of rod length. how can I add K next to the spring??

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.  Fixed now.  BTW, there is a pic for showing angles.

Comment: Thank you so much. can you tell me what exactly scope does??

Comment: scope allows you to make temporary definitions or move the origin.  But since you had no points outside the scope, there was nothing to move the origin relative to.